# Re-structure a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

Suppose I need to reorder a data frame:

```
input <- structure(list(Name = c("Luis_aaa_A", "Luis_bb_BB", "Luis_c_CCC", 
"Jackie_aaa_A", "Jackie_bb_BB", "Jackie_c_CCC"), Age = c(0L, 
8L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

That looks like this:

```
input
          Name Age
1   Luis_aaa_A   0
2   Luis_bb_BB   8
3   Luis_c_CCC   9
4 Jackie_aaa_A  12
5 Jackie_bb_BB  13
6 Jackie_c_CCC  14
```

I want to:

- transform the data frame from long to wide,
- creating a column named `A`, `BB`, and `CCC`, where I put the content of `input$Age` accordingly,
- and ideally, rename the content of `input$Name` removing the unnecessary characters (that are those after the names).

The output should therefore look like this:

```
output <- structure(list(Name = c("Luis", "Jackie"), A = c(0L, 12L), BB = c(8L, 
13L), CCC = c(9L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

output
    Name  A BB CCC
1   Luis  0  8   9
2 Jackie 12 13  14
```

To use `pivot_wider()`, I first create an empty column

```
input$A<-0
input$BB<-0
input$CCC<-0

input %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("A","BB","CC"), values_from = Age)
```

The output is not the desired one, clearly. Which is the correct way to put columns' names into `names_from()`? As you can see from `input`, `input$Name` is difficult to subset, as each row has a different length (otherwise I would have used something like `str_sub()`). And obviously I have no idea how to change the content of `input$Name` (i.e., from `Luis_aaa_A` to `Luis`) after widening the dataframe.
This is a subset of the original data (that has 300 rows).
I am not very familiar with the `tidyverse`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate `Name` with `'_'` and omit the middle part by using `NA` in the argument `into`. Then transform the data to wide with `pivot_wider()`.

```r
library(tidyr)

input %>%
  separate(Name, into = c('Name', NA, 'name')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = Age)

# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#   Name       A    BB   CCC
#   <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
# 1 Luis       0     8     9
# 2 Jackie    12    13    14
```

Comment: Thanks Darren, `separate` is very useful. How would it work if, for instance, I would like to retain the characters after the name (underscore `_` included) (i.e.: `Luis_aaa`, `Jackie_aaa`)? I guess it has to do with `sep` option...

Comment: @LisaTedeschi in this case the separator should be the second underscore. It's hard to be expressed with `separate()`. An alternative is `extract()` and you could pass a `regex` structure into it: `input %>% extract(Name, into = c('Name', 'name'), regex = '(.+)_(.+)')`

Comment: This is wonderful, I'll check out the regex structures for the next time.